# how can I manupilate data from firestore using ngrx/store?

Tags: angular, action, ngrx, store, reducers

I have this type of NgRx effects.

```
  loadServices$ = createEffect(() => this.action$.pipe(
    ofType(serviceReportAction.loadService),
    mergeMap(() => this.serviceReportHttpService.getServices().pipe(
      map((serviceResponse: Array<ServiceApiModel>) => serviceReportAction.loadServicesSuccess({data: serviceResponse})),
      takeUntil(this.subscriptionService.unsubscribe$),
      catchError(error => of(serviceReportAction.loadServicesFail({error})))
    ))
  ));

  onLoadServicesFail$ = createEffect(() => this.action$.pipe(
    ofType(serviceReportAction.loadServicesFail),
    tap(({error}) => {
      console.error(error);
      this.matSnackBar.open('Load services fail.', 'Close');
    })
  ), {dispatch: false});


  loadServiceByCategory$ = createEffect(() => this.action$.pipe(
    ofType(serviceReportAction.loadServiceByCategory),
    mergeMap(action => this.serviceReportHttpService.mergeSevicesByCategory(action.services).pipe(
       map((serviceResponse: Array<ServiceReportModel>) => 
        serviceReportAction.loadServiceByCategorySuccess({data: serviceResponse})),
       catchError(error => of(serviceReportAction.loadServiceByCategoryFail({error})))
     ))
  ));

  onLoadServiceByCategoryFail$ = createEffect(() => this.action$.pipe(
    ofType(serviceReportAction.loadServiceByCategoryFail),
    tap(({error}) => {
      console.error(error);
      this.matSnackBar.open('Load service fail.', 'Close');
    })
  ), {dispatch: false});
```

by using selectors and reducers i want

```
[
  
  {
   category: 'Hair',
   service: [
     {
       name: 'service 1'
     }
    ]
  },
  {
   category: 'Nail',
   service: [
     {
       name: 'service nail'
     }
    ]
  },
```

this type of data from

```
interface ServiceApiModel {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  category: CategoryModel;
  length: string;
  price: string;
  color: string;
  outlet: OutletModel;
  company: CompanyModel;
  createdAt: TimeApiModel;
  updatedAt: TimeApiModel;
}

interface CategoryModel {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}
```

this type of model is used in the effects which kind of selector can resolve this.
I need to build an Effect and I need a value from the store, the problem is that the selector is a selector with parameters.